# Two EAR's one WAS server. Only one session

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websphere, ear

I have an online and a mobile application. Is it possible to do some setting in Websphere application server, so a customer can login in only application at a time. IF already logged from online, and tries to login from mobile, then he should be logged off from Online. Two applications are different, and no connection between them. But for authentication they call a single service, which is inside a separate EAR, and exposes suthentication service as webservice.

Comment: maybe Filter that talk with your authentication provider could be the hint to resolve this problem? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Comment: this is possible. In Spring we can do it. Well idea can be like -